# ArrayDeque add multiple elements

Tags: java, addition, element, arraydeque

Im using `arraydeque` to create list of items and pass them parameters(Items is class)

```
ArrayDeque<Item> Items= new ArrayDeque<Item>();
```

But I have problem with java ArrayDeque. Maybe there are ways to add more than one element at once. 
For example. I want add at the same time `TableType` and `colourOfTable` into ArrayDeque.

In c++ I could have done it with this

```
vector<Item>Items

Items.push_back(Item("CoffeeTable", "brown"));
```

I want to do the same thing with Java. Instead of creating a new obj for every item, as:

```
ArrayDeque<Item> Items = new ArrayDeque<Item>();

Item obj = new Item("CoffeTable", "brown"); 
Items.add(obj);

Item obj1 = new Item("DinnerTable", "Black"); 
Items.add(obj1);
```

But instead of `obj` I want to add  `"CoffeTable", "brown"` at the same time and with one code line (like in c++ example) into the `Items` array.

I tried something like that

```
ArrayDeque<Item> Items= new ArrayDeque<Item>();

Items.add(Items("CoffeTable", "brown"));
```

But then  got the error while creating create method 'Items(String,String)'

Comment: +1 for the better explanation,though first question.

Comment: You may extend ArrayDeque class and implement your own methods for adding new elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simple create the new item in the call of add:

```
items.add(new Item("CoffeTable", "brown"));
```

So you don't need an explicit variable.

Also note that in Java variable names normally start with a lower case character.

Comment: Im new at programing, so im doing some mistakes ^^

Comment: @MartynasŽukovas there is no problem with being new to programming. We all started at some time. As long as you're polite you will get many useful answers even on topics not expected...

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a new object anyway to hold these 2 values.
You can do this:

```
Items.add(new Item("CoffeTable", "brown"));
```

Anything else you come up with will be syntactic sugar for the above

For example: you can add a `static` method to your class:

```
public static Item item(String k1, String k2) { 
    return new Item(k1, k2);
}
```

And use it later:

```
Items.add(item("CoffeTable", "Brown"));
```

Comment: Thanks, now im got what i wanted ^^

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which would surely work. You can add a function to your class itemAdd() as follows:

```
class Samp {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //code.....
        ArrayDeque<Item> Items= new ArrayDeque<Item>();
        Items.add(itemAdd("CoffeeTable", "brown"));
        //rest of code....
    }
    public static Item itemAdd(String tableType,String colourOfTable){
        return new Item(tableType,colourOfTable);
    }
}
class Item{
    String tableType;
    String colourOfTable;
    Item(String tableType,String colourOfTable ){
        this.tableType=tableType;
        this.colourOfTable=colourOfTable;
    }
}
```

Its similar to what u need to do!! Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

For input multiple values in Queue use this:

```
Queue<Integer> q1 = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));
```

You can also use LinkedList instead of ArrayDeque.

With this command you can simply put multiple values in a Queue/Linkedlist.

Comment: This is a 10 year old question with an accepted answer; there is rarely a point in adding another one.